# Use YOLO to classify objects and then use SURF

Tags: surf, yolo

I trained YOLOv2 to detect custom objects like this pic

When I detect objects related to groceries I am going to show the trained custom objects like this pic and when I detect banknotes I want to use SURF to tell whether it is $1 or $2.

[trained custom objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJU3C.png)

In other words, I want to use YOLO to figure out whether it is a bill or not, and then use SURF to distinguish whether it is $1 or $2.
Can I do this without training banknotes?

Comment: Oh I was about to do the same thing for korean grocery product, you did it first haha. Anyway try to use simple OCR instead of SURF, that's what I'm thinking about

Comment: @gameon67 But how can I know if it is bill or not??
And I thought using OCR is difficult because there are many numbers and letters in bills. I found text localization but it's hard to me so I decided to use SURF.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to detect the price on barcode label

Comment: @gameon67 To be honest, I want to detect the expiry date too. Do you have any good ideas?? I used Tesseract-OCR on Android but its accurracy was not good and I tried SWT algorithm but failed..haha

Comment: Why failed and not good? last time I tested to detect expiry date of korean snack using high quality image. I used Tesseract OCR as well and it could detect the date (extract number that appears before '까지' in korean)

Comment: @gameon67 Can you send me a link you referred to??

Comment: I didn't refer to any link, just use simple OCR on high res image